# Trigger codepipeline during update specific key or bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to ask you how can I run Codepipeline when test.json is changed?
I tried to use CloudWatch but trigger was not running

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "PutObject",
      "UploadPart",
      "GetObject",
      "PutObjectAcl"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": [
        "ap-stacks-configuration"
      ],
      "key": [
        "test.json"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my Role. What I am doing wrong?

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codepipeline:StartPipelineExecution"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make the first stage of the pipeline an S3 source that points at your object.

```
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: MySource
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: S3
                Version: '1'
              Configuration:
                S3Bucket: MyS3Bucket
                S3ObjectKey: BucketKey
                PollForSourceChanges: 'true'
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: MyOutput
              RoleArn: RoleArn
              RunOrder: 1
```

Comment: I have already source defined as Github and I can't define more than one source :/

Comment: You can have more than once source.

Comment: If all you want to do is trigger off it, and not use it, then just create another source and don't use the output artifacts from that source.